# Excel Listbox inconsistently has no value after setting the Listindex

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a simple UserForm with two Listboxes and two Textboxes that contain the value of the currently selected Listitem. I am having a bizarre bug where one of the boxes will not populate when the form loads. If I close the form and load it again, then the opposite box will not load. If I close and reload a third time, then it loads the first box but not the second again. Repeat ad nauseum.

**First Load:**

[image: First Textbox loads]

**Second Load:**

[image: Second Textbox loads]

The code should have both Textboxes populated at startup. What is the source of this bug?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 4
        ListBox1.AddItem "Item A - " & i
    Next i
    ListBox1.ListIndex = 0

End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    Dim i As Long

    ListBox2.Clear
    For i = 1 To 3
        ListBox2.AddItem "Item B - " & i
    Next i
    ListBox2.ListIndex = 0

    TextBox1.Value = ListBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_Change()
    TextBox2.Value = ListBox2.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: well for one identifying when a selection is made in a list box is not that easy unfortunately.  It makes it much easier to add a mechanism to know the selection has been made to process the selections.  I will post some code below that checks for selection, you have to run this in a loop if you don't implement a mechanism.

Comment: I would have to see your code, all of it that involves the user form.  The initialization of the textboxes at time of "creation" can be blank based on object properties (F4 when in vba editor) so that when you create the form they go blank.  Think of labels in  form, they always default to Label1, Label2, etc. if you don't force this on initialization or perhaps activate / deactivate / terminate it will default to the properties you see in the Object properties.  So be careful with textboxes and labels.

Comment: Changing `ListBox1.Value` to `ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)` and `ListBox2.Value` to `ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListIndex)` should resolve the issue, but I'm still scratching my head trying to work out why it occurs.  Maybe @MatsMug might have an idea.  (Not sure whether I can ping him like this, or whether I have to ping him on a post he has been active on - I'll try this way and see what happens.)

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code - The code in the question is an MCVE which will replicate the OP's issue.  In a new workbook, create a new userform, add two textboxes, two listboxes, and add the posted code into the form, then run.

Comment: we can't see how and when the form is called.  how it shuts down.  I recently made a form with 4 list boxes, depending on a passed in parameters 1-4 of these lists will be built.  I found if a paremeter that builds all 4 lists is sent in, a selction is made and then the form hides, when you show the form the next time perhaps with only 1 list to be built, only that list changes and the userforms keeps the old data in listboxes that should be clear.  Before you leave the form set the selections or the textboxes, when you show it again it will be as you left it.

Comment: As mentioned below, object properties (in properties window) will over write what you have when a form is created / loaded.  I went through this with labels that I change based on listbox selections, they default to what is in the caption at startup.  It should be an easy fix.  The harder part is determining when a selection is made in real time, that does not have an easy answer.

Comment: Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(0) and Me.TextBox2.Value = Me.ListBox2.List(0) if that is all you are worried about.

Comment: Tested referencing the list item and it corrects the problem.

Comment: I see what you are getting at, now.

Comment: I tested @YowE3K suggestion, it works for for the textboxes and it also works for selecting in listbox2, but a listbox1 selection throws and error: Run-time '381' Could not get the list property. Invalid property array index.  It is as if it loses scope on listbox1.Listindex after initialization.

Comment: actually the debug goes to Me.TextBox2.Value = Me.ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListIndex)

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code Good point - the `List2.Clear` fires the `ListBox2_Change` event, with `ListBox2.ListIndex` set to `-1` (i.e. no selection).  So the change event will need to test that the `ListIndex` is a non-negative number before using it.

Comment: Posting the one that runs as you have commented.

Comment: I think the `ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)` is what I'm after.

Comment: Working code below, Yow3EK was right, it will throw an error without testing for listindex = -1 after the clear.  Compiled and tested.  Thank you to Yow3EK.

Comment: @YowE3K got your ping on the other post, not here ;-)  ...that said this code is dangerously spaghettified. I can repro the problem without needing to jump all over the place by introducing `Private Sub PopulateListA` and `Private Sub PopulateListB` and then the `Initialize` handler invokes the two methods and then assigns the `ListIndex` property to 0 on both listboxes; this leaves the two listbox handlers doing nothing other than assigning their corresponding `TextBox.Text` (what's up with `.Value`?)

Comment: Per my observations, assigning `ListBox1.ListIndex` fires the `Change` event, but doesn't seem to guarantee that `ListBox1.Value` is set accordingly.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I noticed in stepping through the OP's code that the Locals window shows (in the Initialize procedure) the ListBox1.Value starting at `Null` and ListBox2.Value starting at `""` (and on alternate cycles they get switched).  The one that is `Null` gets processed correctly, the one that is `""` sets the equivalent textbox to `""`.  So even that seems weird - why the initial value should change.

Comment: I've got the workaround, but I still have no idea what is causing this bizarre behavior in the first place.

Comment: I also find it interesting that `ListIndex` isn't one of the properties visible in the Locals or Watch windows when looking at the `ListBox1` object.  (But maybe that, and this weird problem, are both related to the fact that a single-selection ListBox and a multi-selection ListBox operate in different ways - perhaps there is a base class and two inherited classes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is from Yow3Ek as much as from anyone.  This code runs as tested without error or previous problem.  Thanks guys, I learned something today.  It was firing on the clear.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 4
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem "Item A - " & i
    Next i
    Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = 0

End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    Dim i As Long

    Me.ListBox2.Clear
    For i = 1 To 3
        ListBox2.AddItem "Item B - " & i
    Next i
    Me.ListBox2.ListIndex = 0


    Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_Change()
    If Me.ListBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    Me.TextBox2.Value = Me.ListBox2.List(Me.ListBox2.ListIndex)
End Sub
```